# Delete duplicate row in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, duplicates

I know this question is asked a lot but every time I try one of the answers at my own database the duplicate row is deleted. What would be the good query for deleting row 2 and 3 from the dabatable down here?

Here's a link to the picture(don't have enough reputation points for an image): [DataTable image](http://www.lensert.com/Kcb.png)

Thanks!

Comment: _What_ is the problem with the approaches you have tried, can you show at least one?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CTE with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT t.*,
           rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, ...
                                   ORDER BY Col1)
    FROM dbo.TableName t
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

This deletes all duplicate rows except one.

If you want to delete all you could use `EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM CTE c1
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM CTE c2
    WEHRE c2.rn > 1
    AND c1.Col1=c2.Col1
    AND c1.Col2=c2.Col2
    AND c1.Col3=c2.Col3
    AND c1.Col4=c2.Col4
    AND c1.Col5=c2.Col5
    ...
)
```

Comment: I am not sure where to put table names etc. I executed the qeury down here but it dind't workWITH CTE AS(
    SELECT t.*,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tsk_TaskName, tsk_Task, tsk_AddDate, tsk_DueDate, tsk_Destination, tsk_History, tsk_Finished, tsk_FinishedHistory
                                   ORDER BY tsk_TaskName)
    FROM dbo.tsk_Tasks t
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1

Comment: I get the following error:Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid object name 'dbo.tsk_Tasks'... And the duplicate rows arrent deleted

Comment: @thijs1095: if `dbo.tsk_Tasks` is invalid that table does not exist. Maybe you should also add the database, presuming it is `MyDB`: `...FROM MyDB.dbo.tsk_Tasks t...`

Comment: The name of my database is DEMO and the name of my datatable is tsk_Tasks. When i try dbo.tsk_Tasks or only tsk_Tasks or demo.tsk_Tasks it wouldn't work either

Comment: @thijs1095: so also `SELECT * FROM tsk_Tasks` in SSMS doesn't work?

Comment: That's a good question. Accually never tried it before but it doesn't work indeed